# Does `javax.imageio.ImageIO` require file locking?

Tags: java, image, io, locking, file-locking

My app is saving images into a folder. Simultaneously another piece of software watches over this folder and prints pasted images.

Problem I've encountered is that printing app can send on printer half rendered image or doesn't react to saved images at all.

I'm using `javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, File output)` to save `BufferedImage` into `png` format.

If locking required please provide a code example with explicit locks. If not explain why.

I've tested on `Windows`, `JRE 1.8`

Comment: Have you attempted to synch the file after writing? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#sync--

Comment: If I understand javadoc correctly `sync` blocks current threads untill buffers are flushed. So it should be called before reading file, hence in printing app. Which can't be edited.

Comment: The main purpose is forcing (or at least requesting) the OS to make sure all data (including metadata) has been persisted to disk. I have seen issues with windows in the past where 1 process writes a file and another reads the file almost immediate and the second process sees the wrong size.

Comment: @BrettOkken how can I prove that this will help?

Comment: The issue isn't that it needs locking. The issue is that it needs complete files, and your present technique cannot ensure that.

Comment: @EJP How come that this isn't a use case for locking? I mean complete write before allow reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should write the image to a temporary file and then rename it to the final file name.  this way the file is completely written before the other app becomes aware of it.

Comment: I've used `FIles#move` with `ATOMIC_MOVE` copy option.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to implement some kind of locking mechanism that files are only read when they are completely written, or not at all.

Comment: Isn't locking is meant for nio only?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java at all. If you like, write a Java program that appends a line to a file every 1sec. And 'cat' (or whatever your OS) that file-being-written every now and then in another shell. You'll see what your other process sees.