# Interprocess file locking test

Tags: java, junit, io, locking

How can I write a JUnit test for `ImageIO.write` to prove that without locking it will cause retained file to be read incorrectly by another process before write finishes?

Comment: You can't prove this in an unit test esp as how this behaves depends on the operating system you use. e.g. on Windows it will lock the file implicitly, so it might appear to work as it locks the file for you.

Comment: I'm using windows and it appears not locking file for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870938